# How can find special row and replace special strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I wrote a todo list script with "add","clear" and "find" argument. I need to pass a "done" argument and script find related row and replace  its first column with another value. How can I do that?

Result of script shows in the follow :

```
0,H,First Task
0,L,Second Task
0,M,Third Task
```

and now i want to execute something like `./todo done 2`, and obtain the following result:

```
0,H,First Task
1,L,Second Task
0,M,Third Task
```

Comment: Welcome here! That is your task, but what is your problem? If you could share your approach and explain what fails about it, we can help you. You probably want to write a shell script with something like `case "$1" in done) sed "$2s/^0,/1,/";;` or what? How do we know?

Comment: You say you want to extend the functionality of an existing piece of software you wrote, but you do not show the source code of that software. This would likely mean that solutions would be mostly unusable as they would not be easy to retro-fit into the existing code.  It's also not clear from the question what is the issue; the script with its handling of arguments, or the manipulation of the CSV file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=todo.list
line=2
perl -F, -pi -lapse '
  $F[0] = 1 if $. == $line;
  $_ = join ",", @F' -- -line="$line" -- "$file"
```

Or with `gawk`:

```
file=todo.list
line=2
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -v line="$line" -F, -v OFS=, -e '
  NR == line {$1 = 1}
  {print}' -E /dev/null "$file"
```

With GNU `sed`, you could do:

```
sed -i -e "${line}s/^[^,]*/1/" -- "$file"
```

But you'd have to sanitise `$line` (make sure it contains a sequence of `[0123456789]` characters) beforehand or otherwise, that would introduce an *arbitrary command execution* vulnerability.

With `gawk`, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
fis=$1
col1=$2
if [[ $fis == "done" ]]
then
awk -v col1="$col1" -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR==col1{gsub(".*","PRAVEEN",$1)}1' ht.txt
fi
```

output

```
0,H,First Task
PRAVEEN,L,Second Task
0,M,Third Task
```

Comment: welcome back! `gsub(".*","something",$1)` == `sub(".*","something",$1)` == `$1="something"`.